# Adding Column to table with SOAP and curl. How to add access token to xml?

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl

I have a simple bash file that gets the access token and then uses a xml file to add a column to a table in Salesforce Marketing Cloud through SOAP API. The problem is that I don't know how to automatically place the access token into the xml file using a variable. I tried "$token" and variations of that with no success. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Get an authorisation Token

token_output=$(curl \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '
{
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "ccccccc",
    "client_secret": "sssssss",
    "scope": null
}' \
https://xxxxxxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/Token | jq '.') 

token=$(jq -r '.access_token' <<< "$token_output") \


curl -XPOST \
-H "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" \
-H "SOAPAction: Update" \
-d @updateDE.xml \
https://xxxxxxxx.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx
```

Here is the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Update</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://xxxxxxxx.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">"$token"</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options /> 
            <Objects xsi:type="ns1:DataExtension" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <CustomerKey>0B35F2DD-6A27-448D-96D8-8CBD7598FD85</CustomerKey> 
                <Fields>
                    <Field>
                        <Name>New Field4</Name> 
                        <MaxLength>200</MaxLength> 
                        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired> 
                    </Field>
                </Fields>
            </Objects>
        </UpdateRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your desired input. What should be inserted and where? Is it the contents of the `$token` variable? Or maybe `"$token_output"`? Or something else? Where should it be placed in the XML file? Should it replace something? Does that something occur only once in the file or do we need to check for a specific line? How exactly did you "try $token with no success"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a known text in place of token, eg. `TOKEN`:

```
...
<fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">TOKEN</fueloauth>
...
```

And then replace that text with the actual token using sed:

```
sed -i 's/TOKEN/'"$token"'/g' file.xml
```

Comment: Why `g` though? That should only be used if we _know_ that all occurrences need to be changed.

Comment: All occurrences do so it's ok. I'm on a Mac so I had to add ' ' after sed -i.